# How to recognize which button was pressed in workflow task outcome

Tags: workflow, lookup-column, workflow-lookup

I am creating a workflow, and I have a modified task outcome with custom buttons. It looks like this:

[image]

When the user presses "Extension Approved" I want the loop in my workflow to continue running, but I don't know how to check which button the user pressed in the workflow. How do I recognize which button was pressed in the task outcome?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out...

I just needed to use the "Task outcome" from the previous task. Then the value had a drop down menu which allowed me to select "Extension Approved".

[image]